# getting an error with play.Project.playJavaSettings

Tags: sbt, playframework-2.3

I have a Java project using play framework v2.3.  I have the following line in the build.sbt file:

```
play.Project.playJavaSettings
```

However, now that I start activator, I get the following error:

```
[info] Loading project definition from /home/username/typesafe/testProj/project
/home/username/typesafe/testProj/build.sbt:60: error: object Project is not a member of package play
play.Project.playJavaSettings
     ^
[error] Type error in expression
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

I have tried the following but I was not able to resolve the build file loading issue

```
playJavaSettings
```

Removing the line works.  I am still looking into if this line really is required for a Java project or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`playJavaSettings` is not available anymore in Play 2.3, since Play is now added via the auto plug mechanism. Check the [migration guide for 2.3](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Migration23) which states that:

> Play itself is now added using the auto plugin mechanism. The
>   mechanism used in Play 2.2 where playJavaSettings and
>   playScalaSettings were used has been removed. You now use one of the
>   following instead

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)
```

Comment: I tried that (as per the documentation) by adding it in build.sbt - threw a new error which I need to investigate.  Accepting the answer since it answers the original question.  Thanks

Comment: you can still use the '.enablePlugins(PlayJava)' ... i ran into this error and this is not the fix i think. i m still getting this error, despite this change tho.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I accidentally used `PlayScala` instead of `PlayJava`, fixed it. But what error are you referring to?

Comment: i get this : object Project is not a member of package play

Comment: Although you did remove the `play.Project.playJavaSettings` line? Mind if you post your `build.sbt` somewhere so one might take a look?

Comment: it s nice of u @edi thanks! i ve tried some stuff and finally got through i think. if i get stuck i ll call in for help :) cheers.